# Cross symbol is showing on SharePoint master page

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2010, sharepoint-2013

I am new in SharePoint.

Can anyone tell me that why cross symbol is showing marked in a rectangle in the following image in SharePoint project?

[image]

Comment: Close all VS instances and clear the VS cache then open fresh instance and connect to TFS then check,,,
also do you installed power tools...?

Comment: give another try Delete the following directory C:\Documents and Settings\<Current User>\Local Settings\Application Data\Microsoft\Team Foundation\1.0
and run devenv /resetuserdata

Comment: @Ankur, I have already done this but not changed.

Comment: Got it. After installing Development Tools Edition(CKSDev), problem was resolved.